# Get html with remove specific element on javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

if my HTML is like this :

```
<tbody id="hasil-pencarian">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td>TMS/IT/06/001</td>
    <td>Erika Julia Widiyanti</td>
    <td>Marketing</td>
    <td>14-06-2015 13:59</td>
    <td>14-06-2015 14:00</td>
    <td>Erika test 1</td>

    <td id="action" class="center" width="10px">
        <a class="btn btn-success">
    </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

I got all the html above like this  :

```
var result = $("#hasil-pencarian").html();
```

But, How can I get all the HTML without the `<td>` with `id='action'` ?
Little confused. Any help will be so appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I think you could create clone then remove the element then get the content like

```
var result = $("#hasil-pencarian").clone().find('#action').remove().end().html();
```